# Laurent series of $\frac{sin(z)}{(z-{\Pi}/4)^3} $ in $0 < |z-\Pi/4| < 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, laurent-series

What will be Laurent series of $\frac{sin(z)}{(z-{\Pi}/4)^3} $ in $0 < |z-\Pi/4| < 1$ ?

I have calculated as ${z-\Pi/4} = t$ => $\frac{sin(t+\Pi/4)}{t^3}$ = $\frac{(t+\Pi/4) - (t+\Pi/4)^3/!3 + (t+\Pi/4)^5/!5......}{t^3}$

Solving and substituting $t = z - \Pi/4$ I get final answer.
Is this the correct way to solve?

Comment: The same as it is now, I guess. This kind of things don't change with time.

Comment: Show us what you've tried. We'll verify it for you. Also type your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to avoid having series in the coefficients, thus use
$$
\sin(t+\frac\pi4)=\frac{\sin t+\cos t}{\sqrt2}.
$$